# ¿Como hacer un contador de ip usando php y mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Que tal compañeros, he querido hacer un contador de visitas para un sitio web (no es avanzado y es solo prototipo) en el que por cada vez que un usuario nuevo visite la pagina el contador incremente en 1 y se añada la ip del usuario a la base de datos, solo que no se la razon por la cual mi codigo no funciona, espero puedan ayudarme. Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
   /*plantilla de la pagina*/

<?php

$con_error='Could not connect';

$mysql_host='localhost';
$mysql_user='root';
$mysql_pass='';
$mysql_db='new_database';

/*

/*connect to server / database*/  
$mysqlcon=mysqli_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die($con_error);

/*select database*/
mysqli_select_db($mysqlcon, $mysql_db) or die($con_error);

?>



    /*codigo que aumenta el contador por ip y guarda la ip*/

<?php
    $user_ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    mysqli_query($mysqlcon, "INSERT INTO hit_ip VALUES ($user_ip)");


    function add_ip () {
        global $mysqlcon;
        global $user_ip;

        $query="SELECT ip FROM hit_ip WHERE ip='$user_ip'";
        $query_run=mysqli_query($mysqlcon, $query);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query_run)==NULL) {
            $ip_query="INSERT INTO hit_ip VALUES ($user_ip)";
            $result_ip=mysqli_query($mysqlcon, $ip_query);
            if ($result_ip) {
                $query_count="UPDATE hit_counter SET value=value+1 WHERE hits='hits'";
                $result_query=mysqli_query($mysqlcon, $query_count);
            } 
        } 
    }


    add_ip(); 

?>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Y por que no funciona?, que error te lanza?, no guarda los datos, guarda datos erroneos?, coloca mas informacion para poder ayudarte de mejor manera.

Comment: si, me falto añadirle el por que je, lo que sucede es que incrementa el numero en el contador pero no añade la IP a la base de datos y sigue contando cada vez que entra el mismo usuario (en caso de localhost)

Comment: mmm de hecho ya vi por que no me añade la ip y es porque no le puse simples comillas a la hora de insertar en el SQL en la parte de $ip_query="INSERT INTO hit_ip VALUES ('$user_ip')"   pero el contador no funciona ahora

Comment: si era por eso jaja, no me habia fijado :$

Comment: Si quieres que se incremente automaticamente, pon un campo autoincrementable directamente en la base de datos no lo hagas a traves de php.

Answer (score 0):

Aqui el problema fue que olvide poner las comillas simples en la parte:

```
$ip_query="INSERT INTO hit_ip VALUES ('$user_ip');
```

y borrar la parte:

```
mysqli_query($mysqlcon, "INSERT INTO hit_ip VALUES ($user_ip)");
```

que la habia introducido como un codigo para probar de manera manual si el query realizaba la accion deseada